# How can I calculate distance map of a flat region using only one image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, point-clouds

I have camera parameters and I know the distance between the camera and the flat region (for example, a wall). Roll and pitch values of camera are constant (assume as in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OFpX.png)). But, yaw value can be any value between -60 and 60 degrees, and also I know this. Is it possible to calculate the distance of any point in the image to the camera location ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. In my scenario, there is no object. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, not without additional information. An object that's not on the "flat region" can be anywhere. To convince yourself that this is the case, note that, given an image of the object, you can always "shrink" it and move it closer to the camera to produce the same image.

If the object has known size and shape, then you can trivially find its distance from its apparent magnification in the image.